# Datepicker month format

Tags: android

When i display a Datepicker in most api versions of android the month is displayed  like this:
[image]

But in api level 10 the month is displayed like this:

[image]

So i want to know if there is a way to force the month to be displayed with only 3 letters and remove the backslash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick study of every [method for DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) has revealed that there is no way to do it through code. I suspect that if the size of it is chosen correctly, the 3 letters might still appear, but I don't have the time to do a trial/error on that hypothesis.